# How to Place Buttons Side-By-Side Xcode WatchKit

Tags: xcode, autolayout, apple-watch

I am working on my first WatchKit app. I wanted to have one button in each corner of the Apple Watch. However, my project ends up looking like this:

[image]

Here is my interface.storyboard:

[image]

How can I put my buttons in the corner? I have aligned each button to the correct place in the interface (e.g. - horizontal left and vertical top for the yellow buttton). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 2 `WKInterfaceGroup` objects and set their alignment as:

Set your groups layout to horizontal and

For 1st `Group` set its vertical alignment to `top`

For 2nd `Group` set its vertical alignment to `bottom`

Now Add two `buttons` in each `group` and set their horizontal alignments:

set 1st button to Left align and 2nd to Right align. do it for the 2nd group buttons too.

For Further assistance and help see [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CreatingtheUserInterface.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using 4 different WKInterfaceGroup objects, but I didn't think of 2.